# How to deal with async ajax calls in durandal activate method?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I have the following in my folder viewModel:

```
  var observableData = ko.observable();
  function activate(routeData) {
     var buildObservableData = function (data) {
         observableData(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping));
         // do stuff here that I need server data for
     }
     return dataservice.getFolder(currentFolderId, buildObservableData);
  }
```

With getFolder as:

```
var getFolder = function (id, buildData) {
   var request = $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: endpoint,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                buildData(data);
            })
            .fail(function (msg) {
                toastr.error("Error: Could not load folder data.");
            });
    }
```

Now, in my folder view, I have this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: data().folders -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

So when I navigate from one folder to another, I get this:

```
"Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'folders' of undefined;↵Bindings value: foreach: data().folders "
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

If I change the ajax call to this:

```
return $.ajax({
```

from this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
```

then I can navigate around my views... but I'm not sure if this is correct.  I'll leave this up in case it helps someone else or in case it's not right.

Comment: The solution you found is the one out of the book http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Model/ solution, so it's correct.
> You can optionally return a promise to tell the activator when your async activation logic has completed.

BTW: You can answer your own question and mark it as solution. Not that you'd get any reputation for it though, but it helps closing questions.

Comment: Pretty late, but wouldn't you want to return the AJAX promise and then in your activate have a done method that would add the data? You've got your stuff all backwards it seems to me. Did this end up working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the ajax call to this:

```
return $.ajax({
```

from this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
```

then I can navigate around my views... but I'm not sure if this is correct.  I'll leave this up in case it helps someone else or in case it's not right.